# Expected unqualified-id before before '{' token?

Tags: c++

the next error shows in my ide

```
expected unqualified-id before '{' token
```

this is my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout<<"=========================================\n";
    cout<<"<<WELCOME TO AGE CALCULATOR APPLICATION>>\n";
    cout<<"=========================================\n";
    int age,days,hours,minutes,seconds;
    cout<<"enter your age in years: ";
    cin >> age;
    days = age * 365;
    hours = days * 24;
    minutes = hours * 60;
    seconds = minutes * 60;
    cout<<"\n"<<"your age in days is: "<<days;
    cout<<"\n"<<"your age in hours is: "<<hours;
    cout<<"\n"<<"your age in minutes is: "<<minutes;
    cout<<"\n"<<"your age in seconds is: "<<seconds;
    return 0;
}
```

[image: the problem in vs code]

tried to close vs code then open it again but didn't work, i use the g++ compiler and it works good cuz i tried it on other little programs that i wrote.

Comment: Please post the error as text. Don't post texts in pictures. Also show your `c_cpp_properties.json`.

Comment: @273 its there, just somewhat hidden

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai It's not verbatim, the location is not shown.

Comment: Seems like vs code is wrong, I copy pasted your code and compiles and runs fine for me.

Comment: [Compiles for me](https://godbolt.org/z/n6f561Wrs). Make certain you have no non-printable characters or unicode characters in there from cut-n-paste shenanigans by inspecting the file in a hex viewer ([example](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.hexeditor)).

Comment: Did you save your file before compiling? I expect you are compiling an old version of code because you did not save your file. Either that or there is some non-printable character between lines 4 and 5.